# Is there any way to speed up array initialization?

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, jagged-arrays

I have a function that stores values inside some arrays. Every time the function is called, the arrays have to be cleared before putting items in them.

```
public static void UpdateAttackedPieces()
    {
        attackedSquares = new List<int>[2][];

        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) attackedSquares[color] = new List<int>[64];

        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) attackedSquares[color][i] = new List<int>();

        checkAttackersRays = new List<int>[2][];

        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) checkAttackersRays[color] = new List<int>[64];

        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) checkAttackersRays[color][i] = new List<int>();

        // Update arrays
    }
```

(It is a chess program and the function is for updating pieces under attack).

`attackedSquares` is an array (one per color) of the 64 squares on the board which holds information about its attackers (so `attackedSquares[0][4][2]` is the third attacker on the fifth square for white, for example)

I've done some testing and about 35% of the time it takes to run the function is spent initializing the jagged arrays. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a problem with the function's runtime performance? Otherwise this seems like premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, this funtion is called repeatedly when looking for all the possible moves and for a simple search of depth 4 from the starting position, from my testings, 19 out of 21 seconds used to generate the moves come from this one function and 6.5 of those seconds are from the arrays initialization

Comment: Your method just isn't doing a ton of work.  Looks like a few hundred iterations total, which should execute absurdly quickly.  How many times was this method invoked during those 21 seconds?

Comment: It was called 216365 times

Comment: I am tempted to challenge the choice of datastructure. The List is surely representing a chess board 8x8, right? And you'll never have more or less than the colors white and black ...

Comment: @EliaGiaccardi is there a good reason this method needs to be called about a quarter of a million times in that span? I'm having trouble understanding why your logic would be written so.

Comment: agreeing on Fildor I allways feel unconfurtable when I see `List<List<ListList<List...>`

Comment: I suppose you're doing a brute force analysis of a game like chess and are thus CPU bound?

Comment: There's not much you can do about that code which will make your code significantly faster, as it lieratelly does nearly nothing. Instead you should try to call it less times.

Comment: To save on allocations, you may want to look at [`ArrayPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @KirkWoll The testing has been done on a perft funtion, a function that generates every move from a certain position and then every opponent's response to that move, and finally returns the total amount of positions after the specified depth. At a depth of 4, there are a quarter of a milion possible positions. https://www.chessprogramming.org/Perft_Results

Comment: I would bet: you'd be better off with a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` where you only have entries where there's actually data and create the list on the fly if you need a new one. The key being an index based on color and field index.

Comment: That's actually very smart, I'll try to implement that

Comment: If you precreate a bunch of empty lists first, then  you can clear them using `List<T>.Clear()`. This does not change the internal capacity, so filling them the first time after will allocate memory, but the next time will not cause memory allocations (unless they become bigger than they were previously)

Comment: I've ended up applying your idea, @MatthewWatson, just because it's literally a change in two lines of code. I've tried with your method Fildor, but I couldn't implement it without creating errors everywhere in the code and fixing them was not an option right now. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Matthey Watson's comment, I was able to bring the time down from 6.5 seconds to less than 1 second with this change in the code:

```
public static void UpdateAttackedPieces()
    {
        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) attackedSquares[color][i].Clear();

        for (int color = 0; color < 2; color++) for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) checkAttackersRays[color][i].Clear();

        // Update arrays
    }
```